# Handling onMouseOver and onMouseOut on a NSStatusItem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsview, nsstatusitem

I have a status menu with a few items inside of all. All of the status items are custom and have custom views inside.

How do I detect when the user's mouse is over the NSView (inside of the item) or status item itself?

Comment: Hey Andrew, I am running into the same problem, but can't get the NSTrackingArea to respond to event. Would you mind updating the question with your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `NSTrackingArea` objects for these things. This class handles exactly what you need.

Comment: Looks perfect. I was looking around but I couldn't find out how to actually RECEIVE the event. I can set up the tracking area, but what gets called or how do you set something to be called?

Comment: You setup NSTrackingArea with needed to receive events (mouse entered/left/hovered/etc) and owner of these events (like view or its controller) which should implement required methods like `mouseEntered:`, `mouseExited:`, `mouseMoved:` or `cursorUpdate:`.